# If I have a table with 200 records (only 1 column). How do I print 20 records after the 100th record?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table named Employee, containing the names of employees. I want to print names of 20 employees, starting from the 100th employee. How do I do that ?

Comment: Which database are you really using? Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really need to mention exact database you are using because this is highly vendor specific.

In **`MySQL`**, you can use LIMIT:

```
select *
from t
order by x, y, z
limit 100, 20
```

In **`Oracle 12c`**, you can use `fetch` clause with `offset`:

```
select *
from t
order by x, y, z
offset 100 fetch next 20 rows only
```

For **`Oracle 11g`** or prior, you can make use of `rownum` with subqueries:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rownum as rn
    from (
        select *
        from t
        order by x, y, z
    ) t where rownum <= 120
) where rn > 100;
```

One important thing to note here is the `order by` clause. A data set in RDBMS is an unordered set of rows. You'll have to *define* an order to according to which you say get rows 101 to 120.